# Image not being downloaded by Glide inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to download an image into an ImageView inside a Fragment, but it seems like the network request does not even get made by Glide. (I use Proxyman to watch network traffic from my physical Android device). I am not sure what else to try.

Here is the fragment code:

```kotlin
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    lateinit var viewModel: ExampleViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentExampleBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentExampleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        (activity as ExampleActivity).appComponent.inject(this)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(ExampleViewModel::class.java)

       // I have also tried `activity as FragmentActivity` instead of this
        Glide.with(this).load("https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg")
                .override(200)
                .into(binding.imageViewFaceTaggingStart)
    }
}
```

Extra details:

- I have read http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html#missing-images-and-local-logs which mentions a few things I could try. I can confirm I call `into()`, am not using Custom Targets, and have explicitly set the size and background colour of the image view to ensure it is not "zero width".
- I am using `FragmentContainerView` inside the Activity.
- Here is a simplification of the XML file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar ...></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <ScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_face_tagging_start"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
         ....more views (TextView, Space, Checkbox)
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try using ```Glide.with(requireContext())``` in a Fragment (Don't know about Kotiln equivalent)

Comment: Try adding a listener  ``` .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                //Todo

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                // Todo

                return false;
            }

        })```

Comment: is this the URL that you are using in app? "https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg" with https

Comment: @sowmia Its just a random JPG file I got off the internet. I tried others

Comment: @MalikBilal, I have just tried `requireContext` (its the same in Kotlin), and I get `D/Glide: Finished loading BitmapDrawable from DATA_DISK_CACHE for https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg with size [200x200] in 3209.5091509999997 ms` Unfortunately its still a black-background `ImageView`. I will try the RequestListener now

Comment: is your URL https or http in your app. As everything else seems fine. Just wanna make sure if you are blocked as you were using http url in your application.

Comment: Do you mean in `https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg`? Its exactly like this one, so `https` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view that is inflated and the view reference i.e. `binding` that you are using are not same,

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    lateinit var viewModel: ExampleViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentExampleBinding


override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentExampleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return this.binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (activity as ExampleActivity).appComponent.inject(this)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(ExampleViewModel::class.java)

       // I have also tried `activity as FragmentActivity` instead of this
        Glide.with(this).load("https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/tiny-png-panda.jpg")
                .override(200)
                .into(binding.imageViewFaceTaggingStart)
    }
}
```

Now the view of the fragment is the `binding`, Try with this.

issue in here `class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example)`

Now the fragment will inflate this `R.layout.fragment_example` not the binding, so the `binding` refers to another view,

Comment: I have just removed usages of view binding and used kotlin synthetics instead, and that worked. So its gotta be something wrong with how I'm using bindings. I will try what you suggest now.

Comment: I'll recommend you to use View Binding. Since kotlin sythetics is deprecated now.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what is the mistake with my code, is it because I am not using `onCreateView`?

Comment: Yes this is why I started with view binding, but after so many hours of trying I switched 

Comment: So my understanding is: `R.layout.fragment_example` is inflated and shown to the user. When I create a new `binding` in onViewCreated, its a little too late and completely useless because this is not the view that is being shown to the user. By moving it to `onCreateView`, we can save the binding but still return this to be shown by the framework.

Comment: Yes, if you override the `onCreateView ` and return own view then, `class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example)` layout passed here will be ignored

Comment: Oh great I can remove that then. I didn't :D